# Center coordinate of a set of CLLocationsCoordinate2D

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, coordinates

Is there any way to get center coordinate of a set of CLLocationsCoordinate2D in iOS?

[image]

Comment: It's hard to define the centre of a set of points. Given the points (1,1) (2,1) (2,2) (1,2) you can get the centre easily but for something like (1,1) (6,8) (8,1) (3,6) it is a lot harder. Can you clear up what you mean by the centre.

Comment: I am having a set of location coordinates of a certain region, from which i need to find center coordinate of that region but its not necessary that region is of some specific shape. It might be a PolyLine or PolyGon.

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "center" I have already given you a way to find the center which you said is not correct. Give an example image or something to show what you want.

Comment: I hope above image can give you some idea of region that can be drawn by user and also it might be quite more complicated and lines might be crossing each other one or more times.

Comment: Yes, but you don't specify on that image WHERE THE CENTER IS! You need to define what you mean by "center".

Comment: Like Fogmeister points out, it depends what you mean by "centre". If someone drew the letter "C", would you want the center to be in the middle of the letter where it is not on the line or do you want it half way along the line or some other method.

Comment: If you want to do something independent of the international date line, you could do something like this: do the calculation in 3D. Assuming the Earth is a sphere is good enough. Transform lat,long into a cartesion coordinate with x,y,z. Then find the average of those point. Next create a vector from the center of the earth, through that point to the surface. Use that as the center of the map and create boundaries to fit all the points. That is probably most easily accomplished by transforming the coordinates of the points to center on our derived point.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hmm... it depends how you define the centre of the points. Does it depend on the distribution etc...

An easy way to do it is as follows...

```
//find rect that encloses all coords

float maxLat = -200;
float maxLong = -200;
float minLat = MAXFLOAT;
float minLong = MAXFLOAT;

for (int i=0 ; i<[locations count] ; i++) {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location = [locations objectAtIndex:i];

    if (location.latitude < minLat) {
        minLat = location.latitude;
    }

    if (location.longitude < minLong) {
        minLong = location.longitude;
    }

    if (location.latitude > maxLat) {
        maxLat = location.latitude;
    }

    if (location.longitude > maxLong) {
        maxLong = location.longitude;
    }
}

//Center point

CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((maxLat + minLat) * 0.5, (maxLong + minLong) * 0.5);
```

This will give the center of the rect covering all the points. However it does not take the spread into account.

i.e.

```
. = point
X = centre

.....               X                   .
```

**EDIT**

Corrected some of the maths.

Comment: This approach is useful when the shape of region is either some scalar shape like rectangle or square or circle or nearly same, but in my case the region is not of any specific shape as I already said, because it is being drawn by user on a map view.

Comment: This works whatever the shape is. It finds the minimum and maximum and then calculates the centre. If you wanted something else then, like I said in my comment, you need to define what you mean by "center". Without clearly defining the center then you're not helping. Maybe an example or two would help, etc...

Comment: This will break if the coordinates span the dateline, but that won't be a problem if the user is drawing since they can't draw that way.

Answer (score 7):

And Swift 5 compatible extension

```
extension Array where Element == CLLocationCoordinate2D {
func center() -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    var maxLatitude: Double = -200;
    var maxLongitude: Double = -200;
    var minLatitude: Double = Double(MAXFLOAT);
    var minLongitude: Double = Double(MAXFLOAT);

    for location in self {
        if location.latitude < minLatitude {
            minLatitude = location.latitude;
        }

        if location.longitude < minLongitude {
            minLongitude = location.longitude;
        }

        if location.latitude > maxLatitude {
            maxLatitude = location.latitude;
        }

        if location.longitude > maxLongitude {
            maxLongitude = location.longitude;
        }
    }

    return CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(CLLocationDegrees((maxLatitude + minLatitude) * 0.5), CLLocationDegrees((maxLongitude + minLongitude) * 0.5));
}
```

}

Answer (score 6):

I know it's really late but someone could read this and help himself
Using Fogmeister answer you could create a MKCoordinateRegion

```
CLLocationDegrees minLat,minLng,maxLat,maxLng;
for(CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate in coordinates) {
    minLat = MIN(minLat, coordinate.latitude);
    minLng = MIN(minLng, coordinate.longitude);

    maxLat = MAX(maxLat, coordinate.latitude);
    maxLng = MAX(maxLng, coordinate.longitude);
}

CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateOrigin = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(minLat, minLng);
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateMax = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(maxLat, maxLng);

MKMapPoint upperLeft = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinateOrigin);
MKMapPoint lowerRight = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinateMax);

//Create the map rect
MKMapRect mapRect = MKMapRectMake(upperLeft.x,
                                  upperLeft.y,
                                  lowerRight.x - upperLeft.x,
                                  lowerRight.y - upperLeft.y);

//Create the region
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(mapRect);

//THIS HAS THE CENTER, it should include spread
CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoordinate = region.center;
```

Greetings!!!

Answer (score 6):

You can also get both the `center` of an array of `CLLocationCoordinate2D`s and a `span`.

```
extension MKCoordinateRegion {

  init(coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D]) {
    var minLatitude: CLLocationDegrees = 90.0
    var maxLatitude: CLLocationDegrees = -90.0
    var minLongitude: CLLocationDegrees = 180.0
    var maxLongitude: CLLocationDegrees = -180.0

    for coordinate in coordinates {
      let lat = Double(coordinate.latitude)
      let long = Double(coordinate.longitude)
      if lat < minLatitude {
        minLatitude = lat
      }
      if long < minLongitude {
        minLongitude = long
      }
      if lat > maxLatitude {
        maxLatitude = lat
      }
      if long > maxLongitude {
        maxLongitude = long
      }
    }

    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(maxLatitude - minLatitude, maxLongitude - minLongitude)
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((maxLatitude - span.latitudeDelta / 2), (maxLongitude - span.longitudeDelta / 2))
    self.init(center: center, span: span)
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
let region = MKCoordinateRegion(coordinates: coordinates)
region.center
region.span
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the average as the center then you sum up all the lats and longs into their own totals and then divide by the number of coordinates you have, pretty standard maths.

(Note this won't work if you coords span the date line)

Answer (score 1):

Fogmeisters answer will work but has 3 errors, which I have corrected below:

```
//find rect that encloses all coords

float maxLat = -200;
float maxLong = -200;
float minLat = MAXFLOAT;
float minLong = MAXFLOAT;

for (int i=0 ; i<[locations count] ; i++) {
CLLocationCoordinate2D location = [locations objectAtIndex:i];

    if (location.latitude < minLat) {
        minLat = location.latitude;
    }

    if (location.longitude < minLong) {
        minLong = location.longitude;
    }

    if (location.latitude > maxLat) {
        maxLat = location.latitude;
    }

    if (location.longitude > maxLong) { //Change to be greater than
        maxLong = location.longitude;
    }
}

//Center point
//The min's and max's should be ADDED not subtracted
CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((maxLat + minLat) * 0.5, (maxLong + minLong) * 0.5);
```

Comment: Three errors? I count two. Also, just comment on an answer rather than stealing it if you are going to copy paste it like this.

Comment: Fogmeister, I did not yet have the rep to comment.  Also, could not submit a correction as it was rejected, and the recommendation from the rejection was to submit a new, corrected answer.  I just followed the recommendation.  And there were in fact 3 errors.

Answer (score 1):

A small Array extension with no magic numbers like `-200.0`

```
extension Array where Element == CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    func center() -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        var maxLatitude: Double = -.greatestFiniteMagnitude
        var maxLongitude: Double = -.greatestFiniteMagnitude
        var minLatitude: Double = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
        var minLongitude: Double = .greatestFiniteMagnitude

        for location in self {
            maxLatitude = Swift.max(maxLatitude, location.latitude)
            maxLongitude = Swift.max(maxLongitude, location.longitude)
            minLatitude = Swift.min(minLatitude, location.latitude)
            minLongitude = Swift.min(minLongitude, location.longitude)
        }

        let centerLatitude = CLLocationDegrees((maxLatitude + minLatitude) * 0.5)
        let centerLongitude = CLLocationDegrees((maxLongitude + minLongitude) * 0.5)
        return .init(latitude: centerLatitude, longitude: centerLongitude)
    }
}
```